# javascript: call function declared in a different .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing some logic in fileB.js that needs to call another function declared in fileA.js. fileA.js declares a function called abc(). How can I call abc() from fileB.js.

Both fileA and fileB are in the same directory.

Thank you

Ps. I am not using this with HTML. I am just running it locally as part of another project I am working on. I am now using node to run it from terminal. But I am not using anything else in these two files. I just have a bunch of really simple functions. No node.js modules or anything...

Comment: Use [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), it supports multiple environments and doesn't require a browser.

Comment: Are you using node.js?

Comment: How exactly are you running fileA?

Comment: so for now I am running it using "node fileB.js"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js isolates each file as a [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), giving each their own local scope to define essentially "*private*" `function`s and `var`s.

With this isolation, `fileA` will need to [export](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) `abc` in order to share it with other files/modules:

```
function abc() {
    // ...
}

exports.abc = abc;
```

Then, `fileB` can [`require()`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) `fileA` with a relative path (`.` referring to the current directory) and use its exported `function`:

```
var a = require('./fileA');

a.abc();
```

Comment: I am marking this as the correct not because I know the other ones do not work. I marked it as the answer because this worked for me and it seemed the most straight forward to implement at first look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node, then in fileA:

```
module.exports = { abc: abc } //assuming that abc holds a reference to your function, declared somewhere above
```

Then, in fileB you require fileA and use what you exported:

```
var fileA = require('./fileA.js');
fileA.abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running it in NodeJS, I'd suggest doing the following at the top of `fileB.js`:

```
var fileA = require( './fileA.js' );
```

However, in order for this to work, the functions you want to use in `fileB.js` should be exported from `fileA.js`. To do this, lets assume that the function `abc()` is what you want to access:

```
// In fileA.js:
function abc() {
    // ... do something ...
}

module.exports = abc;
```

If you want multiple functions/variables/objects available to fileB.js, you can export them all as one object:

```
// In fileA.js
function abc() {
    // ... do something here ...
}

var myObject = {
    propOne: 'foo',
    propTwo: 'bar
};

module.exports = {
    abc: abc,
    myObject: myObject
};
```

Then, within `fileB.js`:

```
// Import the fileA object you just created.
var fileA = require( './fileA.js' );

// Save references to abc and myObject
var myObject = fileA.myObject,
    abc = fileA.abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include both the JS files in the HTML and then simply call them any function anywhere, it will work.

Comment: I am not using the JavaScript in an HTML page. I'm just running it locally for other stuff I'm working on

Comment: What do you mean you are running it locally?

Comment: I'm running it from terminal.

Comment: @zumzum be more specific please. There are many ways to run JS from terminal.

Comment: I am using node... "node fileB.js"